# Исчезновение подсветки у постов в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Я не силён в этом движке. При переходе в какую то рубрику, подсветка у постов исчезает. 
Как это можно исправить?

http://systemiv.pz6.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Залезть в папку с выбранным шаблоном, и поправить верстку